# Local path referencing when using jQuery.getJSON() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-files

I want to obtain the data from an external JSON file in the same directory into my js portion of HTML file.

I've set up a local nodejs server rendering the referenced html file. I tried to use jQuery's `$.getJSON` method, and `console.log()` the referenced JSON file but nothing shows up in chrome console.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/test.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

To test, instead of my local JSON file, I've inputted a URL to json data, and it does display the url information. So maybe I do not the proper pathing of the `test.json` file?

Here's the server portion:

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error,data){
        if (error){
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Error: File Not Found')
        } else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end()
    })
})

server.listen(port, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log('An error has occured: ', error)
    } else {
        console.log('Listening on port '+ port)
    }
})
```

Comment: Probably an issue with your server code. Post that here so people can help

Comment: I tried your code and it works, go to your browser inspector and check for networking activities.

Comment: Thanks! New to asking in stack overflow, sorry about it.

Comment: Nothing about that server is going to serve up JSON data. It only serves index.html